# Looping through a batch file only if the response is "everything is okay"

Tags: windows, batch

I have a batch file that loops through the contents of a directory and compresses the files in the directory as follows;

```
for %%a in (c:\data\*.*) do if "%%~xa" == "" "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7za.exe" a -tzip -mx9 "%%a.zip" "%%a"
```

Seeing that I am using 7zip to compress the file, it returns the message "everything is okay" if it has successfully compressed the file and it then moves onto the next file in any.

What I would like to do is the following;

1. Only move to the next file if the response is "everything is okay"
2. If the response is anything but "everything is okay", the error is logged
3. Since an error has occurred, it attempts to compress the file again
4. Once when it has succeeded i.e. "everything is okay" it goes to the next file
5. Steps 3 & 4 only occur a maximum of 3 times before it gives up and moves onto the next file.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- (1) and (2)

  You can use a combination of labels, `if`, and [returns codes](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/forums/forum/45797/topic/2670878):

  ```
  for %%a in (…) do if … "7za.exe" … "%%a" & if not %errorlevel%==0 (set z_file="%%a" & goto error)
  …
  :error
    echo Something was borked for "%z_file%"! >> Compress.log
  ```
- (3)

  You can call the compression line from the error routine:

  ```
  :error
    echo Error…
    7z…
  ```
- (4) and (5)

  Now you’re getting complicated and beyond the limitations of a batch-file. It *is* possible, but it requires advanced functions and hacks. You can put the compression and error routines in subroutines and call them as appropriate. You can also use `set` to make a counter (e.g., `set /a counter=counter+1`) (this is one reason to enable command extensions) and `if` for logic (e.g., `if %counter% leq 3 call :compress`)

Comment: Why do you have errorlevel defined as a variable e.g. %errorlevel%?. Why would 4 be complex? I would have thought that assuming the first file failed on try 1 it would attempt to compress the file again and if it passed it would return to the loop?

Comment: Errorlevel is a built-in variable. It’s not the *number* of retries that’s complex, it’s the concept itself; batch-files were never meant for advanced functional programming or logic branches like this. Like I said, it *can* be done for the most part, but it won’t be pretty and will require using many of the advanced features of the command-interpreter (including using command-extensions).

Comment: using the `if not %errorlevel%==0 (set z_file="%%a" & goto error)` style, you could make extra error messages, using `goto try2`, `goto lasttry` and use that to count the number of retries. using `call batchlabel` may give the ability to return to where you left off

Comment: Yup, you could do it that way too if you don’t want too many retries (it would result in code-duplication, but it might be a little simpler to write than using a counter).

Comment: @Synetech - What is the `&` symbol used for? The examples I have seen seem to use `&&`

Comment: The double-ampersand waits for the first command to finish successfully before executing the second. The single ampersand executes the second statement regardless of what happens with the first one. Sometimes you need one, sometimes the other; it depends on the logic. In fact, you can use them to simplify (or complex-ify) your code.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Synetech's answer – this is a working script:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set max_try=3

for %%I in (c:\data\*.*) do if "%%~xI" == "" (
    set cnt_try=0
    call :7zip "%%~I"
)
exit /B %ERL%

:7zip
set /A cnt_try+=1
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7za.exe" a -tzip -mx9 "%~1.zip" "%~1"
set ERL=%ERRORLEVEL%
if %ERL% NEQ 0 if %cnt_try% LEQ %max_try% (goto :7zip) else (
    echo Something was borked for "%~1"^! ^(%ERL%^) >> Compress.log
)
exit /B %ERL%
```

It's working fine for me with slightly different conditions (e.g. `if "%%~xI" == ".txt"`)

... and I don't think that I've used any *hacks* :)

Comment: You should try and test out the script beforehand.

Comment: One might argue that `call`ing a label and `setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` are advanced functions.  BTW, why do you think you need delayed expansion? — I don't see where it is used.

Comment: @insane - now it's tested.

Comment: @scott - english isn't my native tongue. Is this better? `... in my opinion i didn't use any advanced functions or hacks`